# Nativescript - If creating an animation set and playing sequentially, promise resolves before animation is complete

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Trying to write a simple app in iOS (for now) to see how this works out.

Using nativescript version 2.4.1 and Angular2

I am creating an array of images to place in an AbsoluteLayout container. I would like these images to slide in one at a time. I loop over and as I am creating the images i also create an animationSet. Once the loop is finished, i play the animations sequentially but the promise resolves before the animation has completes. I would expect the promise to resolve AFTER ALL animations have completed, but this is not the case. I need to do stuff after the animation set has completed. I am doing something like

```
let absoluteArea = <AbsoluteLayout>this.page.getViewById('absoluteArea'),
   animationSet = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        let newImage = new Image();
        newImage.style.backgroundImage = some.jpg;
        newImage.width = width;
        newImage.height = height;

        AbsoluteLayout.setLeft(newImage, leftPosition);
        AbsoluteLayout.setTop(newImage, centerTopPosition);

        animationSet.push({target: newImage, translate: {x: tranlatedLeftPosition, y: 0}, duration: 75 });

        absoluteArea.addChild(newImage);
    }

    animationAction = new Animation(animationSet, true);
    animationAction.play()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('DONE');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Animation set error', err);
        });
```

The console log 'DONE' will get logged long before the animation completes. Am I missing something? Furthermore, if you check the isPlaying property on the animation in the then handler of the animation promise, it's false even though the animation is still playing

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. Please see https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3271.

The workaround for now is to use timeouts